# Change Table Cell Text Color when event form onchange is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I looking for the right way (works in all most any Browser) to change cell table text color (which is a link) when the content in a form change using onchange event. I am using this:

JavaScript code

```
function changeColor(num){
    if (num == "1"){
               cont = num - 1;
               answer[cont] = 1;
               document.getElementById("cell_1").className="cellNumFilled";
        }
```

HTML Code

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>  
   <td><a class="cellNum" HREF="#preg1" title="1" id="cell_1">1</a></td> 
   <td><a class="cellNum" HREF="#preg2" title="2" id="cell_2">2</a></td> 
   <td><a class="cellNum" HREF="#preg3" title="3" id="cell_3">3</a></td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="quesItem">
<p><b>1. [ 1 Pts.]</b> bla bla bla</p>
<p>Answer: 
  <input type="text" name="a6" maxlenght="200" size="20" onchange="changeColor(1)" />
  <input type="button" value="Preview"/> 
</p>
</div>
```

The complete "functional code" is in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwinfg/rMSV2/).

When the content in the input box change, the color in the top of the table must change too. I am using two classes for tag , one by default and another one when content change through 'document.getElementById("idName").className="newClassName";' but doesn't work. Any idea why? or a better and simple way to do that?

Comment: You mind using jquery?

Comment: For now I just want one solution, later I will decide the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting class just remove that attribute like this

```
document.getElementById("cell_1").removeAttribute("class")
```

and then

```
document.getElementById("cell_1").setAttribute("class","cellNumFilled")
```

Comment: I saw that over here in another similar question, but still doesn't work, thanks. Maybe you can help me to guess why? I make the changes in http://jsfiddle.net/edwinfg/rMSV2/17/

Comment: @EFG I got your problem. just remove answer[cont] = 1; (because answer is not defined anywhere) from your script. It is working fine on simple html page. but sorry for jsfiddle. i am still unable to call your method there

Comment: Now is working like you said in simple html, but is working with answer variable, I don't know what happen, but is working, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

try the below :

```
document.getElementById("idName").setAttribute('class', 'className');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I saw that over here in another similar question, but still doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: You code is saying that changepic is not defined in jsfiddle.